# Adding a second variable into an SQL query using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I want to add a second action to the database but when I added in the $tsql2, I get an "An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query":

```
$tsql = "UPDATE dbo.mspClient SET avdesktopProduct='".$_POST['product']."',
avdesktopProvider='".$_POST['provider']."',
avdesktopRate='".$_POST['rate']."',
avdesktopQty='".$_POST['qty']."',
avdesktopDate=getdate() 

WHERE client='".$_POST['client']."'";

$tsql2 = "INSERT INTO dbo.mspArchive SET client='".$_POST['client']."',
avdesktopchangerate='".$_POST['rate']."',
avdesktopchangeqty='".$_POST['qty']."',
avdesktopchangeDate=getdate()

VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, $tsql2);
```

Any help would be appreciated...it's probably something simple.  The $tsql works just fine; this happened when I added in $tsql2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sqlsrv-query.php

```
sqlsrv_query ( resource $conn , string $sql [, array $params [, array $options ]] )
```

You are trying to give two requests instead of one with parameters...

> For statements that you plan to execute only once, use sqlsrv_query().
>   If you intend to re-execute a statement with different parameter
>   values, use the combination of sqlsrv_prepare() and sqlsrv_execute().

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where 'array' comes into place here.  I just need these two actions to work when the form is submitted.  Sorry, I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: the functions expects 2 parameters that are $conn , and $sql ; and optionally an array of parameters. what you gave is $conn, $sql1, $sql2. this is why you have the error message : `An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query`

Comment: why dont you do 2 queries : `$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql1); $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql2); `

Comment: Ok that seemed to work.  Now I'm just getting a 'COUNT field incorrect or syntax error' on the 2nd part....nevermind I see what I did wrong, I need to add params, etc.

Comment: Look your "?" number